# SwiftUI - Environment Variable : Cannot assign to property: 'xxx' is a get-only property

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, environment-variables

I'm trying to set an Environment Variable, following this doc:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues

so here is My Code -

App.swift:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

        
    var body: some Scene {

        WindowGroup {
            
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
                .environment(\.hits, [])
        }
    }
}


private struct HitsArrayKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: [Hit] = []
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var hits : [Hit] {
        get { self[HitsArrayKey.self] }
        set { self[HitsArrayKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

extension View {
    func myCustomValue(_ myCustomValue: [Hit]) -> some View {
        environment(\.hits, myCustomValue)
    }
}
```

but when I'm trying to change \ update the variable in the View, I get Error -

*> Cannot assign to property: 'hits' is a get-only property*

here is the view's code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment(\.hits) private var hits: [Hit]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("GET", systemImage: "plus")
                        hits = []   //ERROR: Cannot assign to property: 'hits' is a get-only property 
                    }
        ...
```

Comment: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/dependency-injection/

Comment: Typically the way to change the value of an environment variable is like this:
 `.environment(\.hits, [])`, not `hits = []`. Since you have a custom modifier
 you can also use `.myCustomValue([])`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine - you can write it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the way to change the value of an environment variable is like this:

```
.environment(\.hits, [])
```

Since you have a custom modifier you can also use

```
.myCustomValue([])
```